# jquery height returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The height property of jquery always returns 0. I am using it along with Bootstrap. Not sure whether it would be of conflict. I went through several online recommended solutions but did not fix it. Below are the code snippets

```
/*html */
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" class="mobNewsEvents">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Events</h3>
<div class="mobEvents"> //need to get the height of this div element
 <ul>
   <li>...</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

/*script*/
(function($){
$(window).load(function(){
    var temp = $('.mobEvents').height();
    alert(temp);
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is the div `hidden` as the `class` value suggests? Then its height *is* 0.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. I'm digging into this. You may be correct. Will let you know if this fixes it.

Comment: Yes it is the display property of one of the parent class apart from the one shown which I forgot to notice. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"` hints that this might be `display: none`. In this case, `height` is not available. Show it, measure it, then hide it.

Comment: It looks like the display property is set to none. I shall give a try. Meanwhile would you suggest any better solution to show, measure and hide it without letting the client know what is happening in the UI?

Comment: Yes it is the display property of one of the parent class apart from the one shown which I forgot to notice. Thanks for your help

Comment: "any better solution to show, measure and hide it" If the height is explicitly set in CSS, you can try parsing the CSS rules (I would not suggest it!); but other than that, I don't know of a way. However, "without letting the client know what is happening in the UI?" is not really correct - the browser will do two re-layouts, but other than the imperceptible delay (unless your document is really complex), the user should not notice anything. The browser will only do a repaint when your JS thread finishes, which will be identical to the already painted screen.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following instead. window.load is not a good way to deal the document elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var temp = $('.mobEvents').height();
    alert(temp);
});
```

In case you have more than one elements with the same class, it will get the first element only.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var temp = $('.mobEvents':First).height();
    alert(temp);
});
```

or alternatively you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var temp = $('.mobEvents').attr("height").value();
    alert(temp);
});
```

Comment: please give credit for the time to appreciate the answer and effort.

Comment: Yes one thing I understand is that class name should not repeat. One more issue was that the display property set to none. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @user2425218 the purpose of defining classes is to repeat the class on many elements. Hidden elements don't out put any events and properties. You should really use `$(document).ready(...)`